# CRUD Drools rule in runtime

Tags: java, spring, drools

I'm new using `Drools`. I have been integrate `Spring` with `Drools` but I don't know how to `CRUD Drools` rule. Is it any technique to `CRUD Drools` rule at run time in using `Spring`?

Answer (score 1):

go through this link might solve problem

This will let you know in more details go throouh the link

[drools_integration_spring_based](https://dzone.com/articles/drools-integration-spring-vs)

Answer (score 0):

If your intended question is to edit the rules in the Drools, then here is the info :

1. Drools as in the latest version uses a maven local repo to store the .drl files.
2. Rules files can be edited either by Drools workbench UI or by accessing the repo remotely and editing it in an IDE.
3. The .drl files are then packaged into a JAR to be used as a rule repository. This can be deployed over a server for accessing against a REST API or referred in any project (Spring for example).